# Is there a graph of 40 vertices of grade 1 to 40?

Tags: graph-theory

I’m trying to check if a graph with $40$ vertices with $deg(v_1) = 1$, $deg(v_2)= 2$, $\cdots$ , $deg(v_{40}) = 40$ exists. 
No other characteristics are known about this graph.

I suppose that a graph like that can’t exist simply because the vertex $40$ cannot have degree $40$. Is my assumption correct or is strictly referred to the hypothesis of a connected graph and it’s not enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the kind of a graph. If it's a simple graph, your argument is absolutely correct. But, if it's not a simple graph, and there can be multiple edges between 2 vertices or loops, then we can have this graph. One of the many possible graphs in that case can be:-

(Note that i'll take $deg(v_i)=i$)

$v_1$ will be connected to $v_2$ with one edge. $v_{2i}$, where $i$ is integer, is connected to $v_{2i-1}$ and $v_{2i+1}$ with i edges each. $v_{2i+1}$, where $i$ is integer, is connected to $v_{2i}$ via $i$ edges and with $v_{2i+2}$ via i+1 edges. Finally, $v_{40}$ will be connected to $v_{39}$ via $20$ edges. It can then have $10$ self loops, with each loop contributing $2$ to its degree, giving $deg(v_{40})=40$

---

EDIT:

Since it was asked to do it do it without self-loops, we can do it in this way:-

Connect **(1)** $$v_{40}->v_{1}, v_2,\cdots ,v_{39} $$
$$v_{39}->v_{2}, v_3,\cdots ,v_{38} $$
$$v_{38}->v_{3}, v_4,\cdots ,v_{37} $$
$$\cdots $$
$$v_{22}->v_{19}, v_{20}, ,v_{21} $$
$$v_{21}->v_{20}$$

Then **(2)** Join $v_{20+2i}$ to $v_{20+2i-1}$.

In this way, for $v_i$, $i\leq 20$, it'll come only i times in the above mentioned "joining". For $v_{20+i}$, $1\leq i\leq 20$, it'll be connected to vertices $v_{20-i+1}$ to $v_{20+i-1}$ via pairing **(1)** $\implies$ contributes $2(i-1)+1$ to degree. Also, it also connected to all the vertices above it, again via **(1)** pairing $\implies$ contributes $40-20-i$ to degree. And finally, another vertex via **(2)** pairing $\implies$ contributes $1$ to degree. Final degree $=(2i-2+1)+(40-20-i)+1=20+i$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm reviewing the notes where this question is being asked. In general, in the discussion it is assumed that all the graphs are finite graphs with no self loops. Multiple edges between two vertices are allowed. I think we can also use this information too.

Comment: @PCNF I've edited. Take a look. Further, it might confuse you a bit, because I know I wasn't able to write it as neatly as I wanted to, so feel free to ask!